# When I want to shut down, I get a screen message informing me that I still have an app open

Tags: windows, windows-10

Task manager says all apps are closed.  How do I stop this from happeing?

Comment: Use the task manager to see what is still open ...

Comment: Task manager is still open  ;-)  Being serious, does the message go away, or remain onscreen?  This happens to me but goes away in <30secs.  ummm, @DavidPostill maybe read the problem again ...

Comment: Some apps can take 30s to close down completely ...

Comment: I've experienced the same and I couldn't track it down, but my suspicions were drivers that were still trying to unload. Drivers are programs without an interface and as such windows knows it has to wait, but can't display what it is waiting for.

Answer (score 0):

Open task manager and check the programs you use daily thats not stopped

Comment: "Task manager says all apps are closed.".